# How to vertically and horizontally center this text inside bootstrap4 columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this bootstrap 4 grid with a row having a height of 200px, and two columns:

```
<div class="row" style="height:200px;background-color:grey">
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <span>How to center this vertically/horizontally</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>This too</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how I can center the text in both columns both vertically and horizontally.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/31/

I have looked at similar question/answers on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find an answer that actually worked in my case.

So how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *lastest* version (Bootstrap 4 alpha 6).

Use the **`align-items-center`** class to vertically centter, and **`text-center`** to horizontal center...

```
<div class="row text-center align-items-center" style="height:200px;background-color:grey">
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <span>How to center this vertically/horizontally</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>This too</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/vaGYMJHA3T

Answer (score 1):

You could center the text horizontally and vertically by centering the elements under both columns.

You will need to add the following three classes

`d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center`

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="row" style="height:200px;background-color:grey">
  <div class="col-md-10 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <span>How to center this vertically/horizontally</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <span>This too</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first class will make the columns display property become `flex`

Answer (score 1):

Add these as classes to your spans `text-center` and `align-middle`.

The documentation for these classes can be seen here:

Typography: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/typography/

Vertical Alignment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/

If this doesn't work, alternatively, you can add divs around the span, give them a class and give the classes the following styles: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/32/

```css
.col-md-10{
  height: 200px;
}
.col-md-2{
  height: 200px;
}

.this-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.that-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="height:200px;background-color:grey">
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="this-div">
      <span>How to center this vertically/horizontally</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="that-div">
      <span>This too</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work if OP didn't have the text in spans, or the spans had the full height of their parent.

Comment: @Abdel I have updated my answer, which should allow OP to apply styles allowing them to horizontally and vertically align their text.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:relative` and `position:absolute` plus `transform:translate()`.

I changed `col-md` to `col-xs` so that you can see the effect in the snippet *(because the snippet is small)*.

I also added `height:100%` to both column so that they take the height of the parent and you can see the that the `span` is centered horizontally and vertically. This will also stay aligned even when you resize the browser

```css
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-2 {
  position: relative;
}

.col-xs-10 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.col-xs-2 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" style="height:200px;background-color:grey">
  <div class="col-xs-10" style="background-color:red;height:100%;">
    <span>How to center this vertically/horizontally</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:blue;height:100%;">
    <span>This too</span>
  </div>
</div>
```